# Print what's in input fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, input, knockout.js, printing

I got a simple page filled with inputs and I need them to be printed with the content typed by user.

So far I can print the input fields but always empty inside.

```js
class VM{

PrintDiv() {
        let self = this;
        var printContents = document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        location.reload();
    }
  }  
    
    ko.applyBindings(new VM);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="print">some text<input /></div>     
    <br />
    <button data-bind="click: PrintDiv">Print</button>
```

Comment: Found the way to do it with this css. Organized and clean. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2001530/8049362

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you want to get text from input field but you are getting HTML from entire `div` with id `print`. Here is simple fix.

```js
class VM {

  PrintDiv() {
    let input = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('print');
    let printContents = input.value;
    document.getElementById('content').innerText = printContents;
    location.reload();
  }
  
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>some text<input id="print" /></div>
<br />
<button data-bind="click: PrintDiv">Print</button>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Already tried but .value is not working, don't know if is not recognized by typescript (.ts)

Comment: Your code snippet is giving error, I tried to adapt the code to mine but still doesn't let me use **.value**

Comment: Of course it's giving error, that's typescript, can't be run in browser just like that. Check it now.

Comment: Feeling closer, but at the moment is printing **undefined**

Comment: yes is just that one posted. If i change the id to inside the input i can get the value of it, but i loose the rest. Would be recommendable do instead multiple prints to get the result? the idea is having alot of input fields in the page so i was looking for something more global. Thanks for your time

Comment: Read knockout tutorial then, you can find lots of useful examples. Follow them and you will get what you need. You won't learn much by coping and pasting code.

Comment: True, but already saw this question without giving answer, not related to knockout.
 I feel is just a problem of syntax of typescript that I'm not finding to solve the printing.

Comment: That code is working, tried running it and no error etc.

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain myself properly, as i said in a previous comment I can retrieve the value inside of the input this way, but i loose the rest of the info. I need a printed page that contain all the information plus the inserted text fields visible. At the moment the code is only giving the text inserted, if change the print area to the **div** I can't see the inserted text getting a **undefined*. I really appreciate all the help you given so far. Thank you.

Comment: Make new div element with id `content` and change that div content to input value. See example, made edit.